# Bulk Collect V/S Simple Update in DBMS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

Query1 :

```
UPDATE employee
     SET key1 = NULL,
         status = 'COMPLETE'
  WHERE key2 = <someId>
   and  status IN ('APPROVED','AVAILABLE','UNPAID');
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT employee_id
      BULK COLLECT INTO l_Ids
      FROM employees
     WHERE key1 = <somekey>   -- Bug 26721012
     and status IN ('APPROVED','AVAILABLE','UNPAID');

FORALL i IN 1 .. l_Ids.COUNT 
 UPDATE employees
     SET key1 = NULL, -- Bug 26721012
         status = 'COMPLETE'
     WHERE invoice_id = l_Ids(i).employee_id;}`
```

This piece is a part of PLSQL Procedure. Lets assume both the queries has bulk data to be updated. My understanding is that for the first query, the update will happen one by one , while for the second query there is BULK collect which might be faster. However there would be two context switching between sql and plsql engines. Can you please explain which query would be optimizing when bulk data is being updated

Comment: mySQL <> sql-server, and you mention PLSQL, which suggests Oracle. Which is it? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: a) you tagged this question for mysql and (ms)-sql server, but not oracle b) your two code pieces do not do the same thing c) There is absolutely no use of bulk collect in this situation (so using query 1 will be fine) d) if you want to ask something about a different situation, ask about a different (actual) situation.

Answer (score 0):

Out of these two options first query would be more efficient and faster.

From your first query it is clear that you just need to update the data in a table based upon a filter criteria. This could be easily done in SQL itself without first loading data in a collection and then updating the same.

Bulk collect is favored in place of cursor if you have to take some action on each row of the table.